Can Le Creuset ware be used on an induction stove?
I am about to buy a Le Creuset set and wonder if the skillet can be used on an induction stove.

https://www.lecreuset.co.uk/en_GB/induction/cap0091.html tells us:

Induction hobs work well with any cookware with a high iron (ferrous metal) content at the base. Our Enamelled Cast Iron*, Stainless Steel, and Toughened Non-Stick cookware are all suitable for induction hobs, as are our enamel-on-steel kettles.
*Exception on our Cast Iron Reversible Grill and Cast Iron Large Crepe Pan. Please refer to the heat source information that we have available for each product.

